# How do I get tcpsvd to drop its root privileges?

Tags: root, non-root-user

Assume a script runs on boot as root. From this script I want to start `tcpsvd -E 0 515 lpd`. I want `tcpsvd` to run as an unprivileged user. But it requires root privileges to bind to the port 515. How can I achieve this?

Further I have to use `busybox tcpsvd`:

```
tcpsvd
tcpsvd [-hEv] [-c N] [-C N[:MSG]] [-b N] [-u USER] [-l NAME] IP PORT PROG

Create TCP socket, bind to IP:PORT and listen for incoming connection.
Run PROG for each connection.

    IP              IP to listen on. '0' = all
    PORT            Port to listen on
    PROG [ARGS]     Program to run
    -l NAME         Local hostname (else looks up local hostname in DNS)
    -u USER[:GRP]   Change to user/group after bind
    -c N            Handle up to N connections simultaneously
    -b N            Allow a backlog of approximately N TCP SYNs
    -C N[:MSG]      Allow only up to N connections from the same IP
                    New connections from this IP address are closed
                    immediately. MSG is written to the peer before close
    -h              Look up peer's hostname
    -E              Do not set up environment variables
    -v              Verbose
```

Comment: It says right there: "-u USER[:GRP]  Change to user/group after bind".  What more did you need?

Comment: Thats fine thank you. I hoped to find a way to do it in a more generic way with su,sudo,etc.

Comment: Now I am at the point where I get into trouble. `$BUSY/busybox tcpsvd -u manuel:manuel -E 0 515 $BUSY/busybox lpd /var/spool zenity --error --text "$DATAFILE"` returns nothing. $DATAFILE is set by lpd. lpd is run as manuel but the environment is root. How do I change this behaviour?

Comment: The shell expands `$DATAFILE` when you type that command, not when `lpd` executes `zenity`.  You need to put the `zenity` command into a shell script, and have `lpd` call that script.  Then `$DATADIR` will be expanded at the right time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have the program bind to the port while running as root, and then switch to your unprivileged user.  `tcpsvd` offers the `-u` option for doing this:

```
 -u user[:group]
          drop permissions.  Switch user ID to user’s UID, and group ID to
          user’s primary GID after creating and binding to the socket.  If
          user  is  followed  by a colon and a group name, the group ID is
          switched to the GID of group instead.  All supplementary  groups
          are removed.
```